# Meteor: call method to execute shell (clone git repo)

Tags: git, bash, shell, meteor

### problem:

In Meteor, how can I call a method from the client (passing `name`), have the server execute some shell commands?

The method function is basically: create a directory and then clone the git repo with the given `name`.

This is *extremely* simple stuff, but Meteor just won't do it. I've been going in circles for hours. everything works in regular bash or node. At the minute:

directory is created -> the server restarts -> meteor throws an error claiming the directory already exists -> meteor deletes the directory -> the server restarts

### code:

```
var cmd, exec, fs;

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.app.events({
    'click button': function() {
        Meteor.call('clone', "NAMEHERE", function(error, result) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log(result);
          }
        });
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  fs = Npm.require('fs');
  exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;
  cmd = Meteor.wrapAsync(exec);
  Meteor.methods({
    'clone': function(name) {
      var dir;
      dir = process.env.PWD + "/projects/" + name;
      cmd("mkdir " + dir + "; git clone git@gitlab.com:username/" + name + ".git " + dir, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
          throw new Meteor.Error('error...');
        } else {
          console.log('done');
        }
      }));
      return 'cloning...';
    }
  });
}
```

**update 1**

The following code will successfully clone the repo if I create the folder manually beforehand:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.all.events({
    'click button': function() {
      Meteor.call('clone', this.name);
    }
  });
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;
  cmd = Meteor.wrapAsync(exec);
  Meteor.methods({
    'clone': function(name) {
      var dir, res;
      dir = process.env.PWD + "/projects/" + name;
      res = cmd(git clone git@gitlab.com:username/" + name + ".git " + dir);
      return res;
    }
  });
}
```

However, if I add `"mkdir " + dir` to `cmd`, I still have the same problem:

directory is created -> the server restarts -> meteor throws an error claiming the directory already exists -> meteor deletes the directory -> the server restarts

### solution:

Meteor was restarting because something in its directory changed (`projects`). The method was then re-run on startup. It was a separate issue to the method call.

The code from **update 1** / @Rebolon's answer is the solution.

Comment: You have embedded a lot of metadata in your question ("(Solved)" in the title, the "solution" header and paragraph...). This metadata is already being taken care of by the format of StackOverflow - The accepted solution is in green, your question is clearly shown as answered... There is no use in adding further data in the question itself rather than in comments.

Comment: @Kyll I didn't add any data. I corrected some grammar and moved a heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Meteor.call is ok, the problem seems to be on the server side :
you use correctly wrapAsync to package the exec npm object, but then you mis-use the cmd var : you only have to send one parameter like this :

```
var res = cmd("mkdir " + dir + "; git clone git@gitlab.com:username/" + name + ".git " + dir);
return res;
```

Actually your code show that you want to return to the client different informations :

1. I received the call and the command is pending
2. The command has finished and is ok or is on error

But in fact it cannot work because with wrapAsync cmd(...) will wait until it's finished before going to return "Pending ..."
So the client will only receive the "Pending ..." response.

Do you really need to inform the client that the command is pending and then it's finished ? If yes, you may use a Status Collection where you could store the status of a command (received/pending/ok/error...) and then in your methods you will only have to update the collection, and in your client side just subscribe to this Status Collection.

You may have a look at this project where i use exec on server (with retry package) and a collection to manage the pending status : https://github.com/MeteorLyon/satis-easy

Comment: Thanks for this. No, I don't need inform the client at all, so I have removed those returns. 

The code above restarts the server -> throws error `fatal: destination path... already exists` -> restarts the server again. 

I removed the `mkdir` from `cmd`, created the directory manually before calling and it works correctly.

Can `res` call another function, say if I want to use `fs.mkdir`?

Comment: Got it: meteor is restarting because something changed in its directory. Renamed `projects` to `.projects` and it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: cool, i think it's possible to make multiple call with res. If you add ~ at the end (or the beginning i don't remember) of a folder, it won't restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Meteor.call` code is not in the function block for your event. Something like this should work:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.app.events({
    'click button': function() {
        Meteor.call('clone', "NAMEHERE", function(error, result) {
          if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
          } else {
            return console.log(result);
          }
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using coffeescript, I just did a quick js2.coffee without checking this properly. thanks though

Comment: @offthegrass and so the problem still here ?

Comment: @Rebolon yes, I still have the problem